# Unbind, or Reset all jQuery Events

Tags: jquery

I have a page that I have a product configurator on, this configurator uses ajax .load to load up the configurator for different products.

If someone configures a product, clicks submit, the product is added, if the user selects the configurator again, and loads that same product, all of the events for the configurator are doubled. Meaning, all the events fire twice...

What would be the best way to reset these events, or prevent these events from firing more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `.live()`.

I found the easiest solution for me was to put a `.die()` before each `.live()` statement.

Example:

```
$('.add').die();
$('.add').live(...............
```

http://api.jquery.com/die/

Comment: Both `.live` and `.die` were [deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/die/) in 2011, removed in 2013.  Flagging answer for deletion as per [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/how-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what syntax you use to bind but if you are using jQuery 1.7 using [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you can this:

```
$("#myButton").off("click").on("click", function(){
    // ....
});
```

That will ensure all click events are unbound first and then your click event is bound.
However, this comes with risks, if you have many click events bound through namespaces they might also get removed even if that was not your intention.

If an event is using a namespace it may look like this:

```
$("#myButton").off("click.myNamespace").on("click.myNamespace", function(){
    // ....
});
```

If you need to have an event bound and only want to use it ones and then have it unbind automatically you can use [**one()**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) like this

```
$("#myButton").one("click", function(){
    // ....
});
```

Just to clarify you can off course just use `off()` or `unbind()` by themselves without chaining them to `on()` or `bind()`, etc.. Word of caution though on `unbind()` if you happen to use `live()` for your bindings. One of the many drawbacks of `live()` is:

> The .live() method interacts with other event methods in ways that can
>   be surprising, e.g., $(document).unbind("click") removes all click
>   handlers attached by any call to .live()!

**Additional Resources**

[**click()**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) - is similar to bind
[**bind()**](http://api.jquery.com/bind)  - preferred binding for static elements pre jQuery 1.7
[**live() (don't use)**](http://api.jquery.com/live)  - deprecated since 1.7 but don't use pre 1.7 either
[**delegate()**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)  - preferred binding for dynamic elements pre jQuery 1.7
[**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)  - preferred binding for static/dynamic elements since jQuery 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are binding the events, you will want to use `.unbind()` or `.off()` (if you are using `.live()` it is deprecated and you should switch to `.on()`)

jQuery has a nice page on [Namespaced Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) which illustrates how to only unbind the event handlers you added.